# Graph series label modification

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
chart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(dt1.Rows[i].ItemArray[0], dt1.Rows[i].ItemArray[3]);
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "{#'%'}";
chart.Series[0].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
chart.Series[0].Label = "#VALY{P1}";
chart.Series[0].CustomProperties = "BarLabelStyle = Right";
```

Its code for creating chart,in there series label i am getting 8000% instead of 80% can you help me how to solve.

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCcS9.png is this image.

Comment: What control you are using as `chart`?

Comment: asp .net chart control.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the value you are binding to the view but I'm going to guess its 80 so you need to change this :

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "{#'%'}";
```

to this

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "{#}%";
```

The percentage format will automatically multiply your values by 100 that's why you are getting 8000 instead of 80.

Comment: chart.Series[0].Label = "#VALY{P1}"; here I need to change the value . so can you tell me any modifications can do there ?